# RuntimeError: Found dtype Double but expected Float on call to backward

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following PyTorch deep learning code in the middle of a training loop:

```
        loss.backward()
```

`loss` has the following value:

```
tensor(434.3251, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

I am getting this error:

```
  File "[,,,]/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 154, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: Found dtype Double but expected Float
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?  I can provide more context if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data type of model's weights, input tensor, and label tensor.

There might be a type mismatch and the automatic conversion of the type.